# Entry control expands beyond StackLayout container

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm using the following (test) code to dynamically create a Page Content. I'm expecting the Entry control to stay within the StackLayout bounds and clip its large Text value. Somehow this doesn't work like I want.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public MyPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        var stackMain = new StackLayout() {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Spacing = 2,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow
        };
        Content = stackMain;

        Padding = new Thickness(15, Device.OnPlatform(25, 5, 5), 15, 10);

        var label = new Label() {
            Text = "Test:"
        };
        stackMain.Children.Add(label);

        var stackEntry = new StackLayout() {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
        };

        stackMain.Children.Add(stackEntry);

        var entry = new Entry() {
            Text = "Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            IsEnabled = false,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        stackEntry.Children.Add(entry);

        var button = new Button() {
            Text = "Click me"
        };
        stackEntry.Children.Add(button);

    }
```

[image: This is working (short text)]
[image: This is not working (long text)]

Comment: Why not use a Grid?

Comment: @Bill Reiss: A Grid isn't suitable for my solution. The test code in this question is purely for demonstrating my issue. The real app is far more complex and, trust me ;), I really need StackLayout for that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an editor, Entries are one line only, the code below is tested and it fixes the Height by the size of the text:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        var content = new ContentPage
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(15, Device.OnPlatform(25, 5, 5), 15, 10),
            Title = "test",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Spacing = 2,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Test:"
                    },
                    new Editor {
                        Text = "Blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        IsEnabled = false,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
                    },
                }
            }
        };

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The text is always a single line. Problem is that it won't work if that one line is exceeding the maximum wide. It works (= clipped text with " ...") when I don't put it in a StackLayout. Problem with an Editor is that it doesn't have a border without using custom rendering which is what I try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same problem on an editor control!

The problem is here `Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal`,

you need to set orientation as `StackOrientation.Vertical` and it will wrap properly.

Note that I'm using Editor instead of Entry.